# Python Удалить Logger

Tags: python, логирование

Вопрос, есть ли хороший способ удаления Logger в Python.

В программе одновременной выполняется несколько экземпляров
задачи обработки данных. Нужно сделать логирование этих 
данных по отдельности для каждой задачи и общее логирование.
Лог по каждой задаче нужно разложить по файликам.

Это можно сделать путем использования для каждой задачи своего логгера
со StreamHandler, у которого в качестве stream использовать StringIO.
Когда задача завершится из нее можно будет получить лог считав его из stream.
После этого логгер больше не нужен и его можно удалить. Но
python модуль logging не предоставляет возможности удаления логгера.
Например об этом сказано тут:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-November/615602.html

Можно удалить используя:
logger.manager.loggerDict,
но это будет своего рода хак.

Как вариант можно сделать pool (набор поочередно используемых) логгеров, 
с размером пула равным максимальному числу одновременно работающих задач.
(Сейчас временно так и сделано).

Если кто знает хороший вариант удаления логгера, поделитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:** Оставить всё как есть + чистка

Если в Вашем коде таких задач не много, то нет смысла париться насчёт логгеров, хватит простой чистки их хандлеров: `some_logger.handlers = []`

Если таких задач и логгеров много, то в принципе да, можно залезть внутрь самого модуля, удалить ненужные логгеры из `logger.manager.loggerDict`. Но тогда если вероятно есть проблема в архитектуре.

---

**Вариант 2:** Написать свой логгер

Логгеры в Питоне созданы, чтобы один логгер использовался в разных местах*, Вам же нужен всего лишь отчёт по выполнению задачи, на что вполне хватит файла или `StringIO`, открытого перед выполнением задачи, и закрытого после.

---

**Вариант 3:** Пересмотреть архитектуру

Идеального решения в такой ситуации видимо нет, зато можно поменять саму ситуацию :) Например, те задачи можно запускать отдельным процессом Питона, по завершению которого его логгеры и вообще всё будет удалено из памяти.

Накидал простой пример с использованием [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Файл `main.py`, основной процесс:

```py
import subprocess
import os

path = os.getcwd()
# можно передавать аргументы
args = ['python3', os.path.join(path, 'task.py'), 'pi=3.1415']
subprocess.run(args)
```

Файл `task.py`, отдельный процесс для подзадач:

```py
import sys

# можно использовать аргументы
# вообще, для парсинга аргументов консоли есть мощные либы
txt = repr(sys.argv)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

Содержимое полученного `output.txt`:

> ['/Users/AivanF/Desktop/task.py', 'pi=3.1415']

Любые созданные логгеры и прочие объекты во втором файле (т.е, в отдельном процессе) будут удалены по его завершению.

Comment: Спасибо. 1. Вариант 1 фактически сейчас использую, имея грубо говоря 100 разделяемых логеров. 3. Вариант 3. В отдельный процесс вариант конечно, но задач таких много. Фактически это обработчики запросов от клиентов на сервере. И такой лог нужен только для определенной группы запросов. Сами запросы обрабатываются через gevent, думаю что выносить их еще в подпроцессы не эффективно будет. 2. Над вариантом 2 надо подумать, может быть получится что-то соорудить.